# How to highlight Google Places items in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Iv noticed that the rendered map is already marked by piously plotted places, I assumes its those plated by people via the regular Google Places business listing website but these places are faintly marked as tiny labels without any protruding markers.

Is there any way to read this data and re-mark these places with my own markers?

Answer (score 0):

With the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript?hl=fr-FR) you can use [PlacesService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr-FR#PlacesService) to get results for search. For each [Place Result](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr-FR#PlaceResult) you can create a custom marker (with your own icon) using the associated position (see `placeResult.geometry.location`).